# Exception when transforming image

Tags: assets, image-transforms

When transforming images, we’re getting the following error on the client’s production server.

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> Argument 1 passed to Craft\AssetTransformsService::ensureTransformUrlByIndexModel() must be an instance of Craft\AssetTransformIndexModel, null given, called in /craft/app/services/ResourcesService.php on line 223 and defined

As a consequence image elements on the page don’t appear. When reloading the page a second time images are displayed as expected.

What might be the cause of this?

---

**Edit**

As requested in comments…

The .htaccess, below-pasted, is just the default.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The template transform is very simple.

```
<img src="{{ block.image.first().getUrl({ width: 560, height: 310 }) }}" alt="">
```

The transform does work but only displays on the second page load.

Comment: Could please you add your template-code, so we can make sure the issue is not in there.

Comment: Would also like to see your public html .htaccess code as well.

Comment: Can you enable devMode (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), reproduce the error and share the full stack trace?

Comment: I'm about 99% sure this was a bug that has been fixed by the latest release. Are you still seeing it?

Comment: Thanks, @BradBell. I haven’t got access to that environment to check. Will follow up if it surfaces again.